# Problema ao Gerar apk ionic 3

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugin, ionic3

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que necessita ler um Qr Code, porem tenho um problema ao gerar o .apk no ionic 3.0. Quando subo a aplicação no ionic view funciona normalmente (abre a câmera e faz a leitura), no emulador NOX também funciona, porem quando gero o .apk o aplicativo abre normalmente porem o botão de captura não funciona, o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Está apresentando algum erro no console? Conecta no USB, abre o chrome e entra no endereço chrome://inspect/#devices e vê no console se aparece algum erro

Comment: Resolvido ! Acontece que não estava executando o CLI em modo administrador .